# Not able to rebind use case of cameraX

Tags: android, android-camerax

I can able to unbind `image analysis` use case. But not sure how to rebind the same when I restart my flow again.

This is how I am unbind it:

```
CameraX.unbind(imageAnalysis);
```

Answer (score 0):

You rebind a use case the same way you bound it the first time, using `CameraX.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, imageAnalysis)`.

Note that CameraX has now [reached RC](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera#1.0.0-rc01), if possible you should upgrade to the latest version (currently 1.0.0-rc01), which is more stable.